# Find longest substring without certain character in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

My question is - how can I find a length of the longest substring without certain character?

For example, I want to find a length of the longest substring without letter 'a' in the string 'cbdbabdbcbdacbadbcbbcda' and the answer should be '7' - the longest string without 'a' is 'dbcbbcd'.

What are the possible ways to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: "What are the possible ways to do it?": many, but I don't think that's really your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string by the certain character, in this case "a", count the lengths of the substrings, and get the maximum.

```py
string = 'cbdbabdbcbdacbadbcbbcda'
avoid = 'a'

longest_substring = max((len(substring) for substring in string.split(avoid)))
print(longest_substring)
```

This outputs 7.

You can obviously split the comprehension up into multiple lines etc. if that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: No need for the square brackets: `max(len(....avoid))` works fine as well.

Comment: Indeed. I tend to include it, as supplying a `key` parameter will cause it to break otherwise (i.e. `max(len(...avoid), key=lambda x: ...)`. That said, I should definitely use round brackets instead of square ones - no need to fully create the list before letting `max` do its thing.

Comment: Could also easily modify this to get both the length and the substring (well *a* substring in the case of multiple max lengths)... eg: `length, substring = max((len(ss), ss) for ss in string.split(avoid))`

Answer (score 0):

A regex based approach might use `re.findall` with the pattern `[b-z]+`:

```py
inp = "cbdbabdbcbdacbadbcbbcda"
longest = sorted(re.findall(r'[b-z]+', inp), key=len, reverse=True)[0]
print(longest)       # dbcbbcd
print(len(longest))  # 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple for loop to achieve this.

```
string = 'cbdbabdbcbdacbadbcbbcda'
avoid = 'a'

max_count, curr_count = 0, 0

for char in string:
    if char != avoid:
        curr_count += 1
    else:
        if curr_count > max_count:
            max_count = curr_count
        curr_count = 0 # Reset curr_count

print(max_count)
```

Output:

```
7
```